# Maximum HTTP Packet Size

Tags: http, get, amazon-s3, network-protocols, packet

What is the maximum size of HTTP packets? I am interested in the size of the response to an HTTP GET request (Not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)! This question is about the request size). Is there a size at all? If I download a 1GiB file, does that end up as just 1 HTTP GET request? (Intuitively, I do not think this happens - Also, partial downloads / multi threaded downloaders would not work).

I know that there is a maximum length of an IP packet and TCP packets that are longer than that are fragmented across multiple IP packets. Does such a thing happen with HTTP as well? The reason I am looking for an answer to this question is to figure out the AWS S3 billing scheme which charges 1c / 10K get requests. So how many GET requests are begin served for 1GiB.

Comment: You can certainly download an entire 1Gb file with a single HTTP GET request. If the server supports byte-range requests, an HTTP client could just as easily make 1,073,741,824 GET requests and download the file a single byte at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer on [AWS S3 Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=394585) by [Seungyoung Kim](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=232455)

> If you download the 5GiB file using GET request. S3's billing system
>   will count it as 1 GET request and 5GiB data transfer. FYI, if you
>   stop downloading file at 2GiB out of 5GiB, then they will count only
>   2GiB data transfer.
>
> GET request is not fragmented normally unless you split up the call
>   into several consecutive GET range calls.
>
> So, if you issue 5 individual GET requests using range header for each
>   1GiB data block, they will count it as 5 GET request but still same
>   5GiB(1GiB x 5 times) data transfer. Technically little more than 5GiB
>   due to additional HTTP protocol headers.

If this is right, there is no packet fragmentation of HTTP GET Response (although they come across several TCP packets and a lost TCP packet is handled by TCP and does not illicit another GET  request to resume)

Comment: Let me know if anyone knows of any exceptions to this.